# Logging into app works in teminal but doesn't work on screen

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, authentication

I am using Rails 4.2.4 and Ruby 2.2.3 When I try to log into my app (which worked yesterday) I get returned to the login page but this output from the terminal seems to show that the user page is loading.

Started POST "/sessions" for ::1 at 2015-09-24 11:15:57 +0100
Processing by SessionsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"AqM2r5Md+yfBZfZ3ylZEEx59tObuKpOk0zTG4It3CRN/JSmleTl+k3zJds+wKvxhl4Lv0DntzRDFwkw2fGJAsw==", "login"=>"gleb", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "commit"=>"login"}
  User Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
  User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."login" = ? AND "users"."password" = ? LIMIT 1  [["login", "gleb"], ["password", "souhami"]]
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/users/1
Completed 302 Found in 5ms (ActiveRecord: 0.6ms)

Started GET "/users/1" for ::1 at 2015-09-24 11:15:57 +0100
Processing by UsersController#show as HTML
  Parameters: {"id"=>"1"}
  User Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
  User Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
  Comment Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "comments".* FROM "comments" WHERE "comments"."user_id" = ?  [["user_id", 1]]
  Subcomment Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "subcomments".* FROM "subcomments" WHERE "subcomments"."comment_id" = ?  [["comment_id", 67]]
  Subcomment Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "subcomments".* FROM "subcomments" WHERE "subcomments"."comment_id" = ?  [["comment_id", 68]]
  Subcomment Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "subcomments".* FROM "subcomments" WHERE "subcomments"."comment_id" = ?  [["comment_id", 71]]
  Subcomment Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "subcomments".* FROM "subcomments" WHERE "subcomments"."comment_id" = ?  [["comment_id", 72]]
  Rendered subcomments/_subcomment.html.erb (47.0ms)
  Rendered users/show.html.erb within layouts/application (49.7ms)
``Completed 200 OK in 55ms (Views: 50.8ms | ActiveRecord: 1.9ms)

Any comments, anybody?

Comment: Signing in also creates a session in the database but still no user page?

Answer (score 0):

Need a lot more information about your controllers/environment in general.  Those lines you provided only show that the authentication SQL query is working and then subsequent queries are being called.  I think you need to be looking for an action on the controller that would send the user to a different page, perhaps the index page.  Please provide controller code that is used for auth when interacting with model/DB.  Also, if you use the password 'souhami' for anything important I would change it since it's in plaintext there.